# Can't Get AJAX Success Message To Work

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Racking my brains for hours with this. I have the following PHP AJAX script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#submitValue").click( function(){
    var uemail=$("#uemail").val();
    var uage=$("#uage").val();
    var city=$("#city").val();
    var urname=$("#urname").val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url:"acctUpdate.php",
        data: "uemail=" + uemail +"&uage="+ uage +"&city="+ city +"&urname="+urname +"&uname="+"<?php echo $memName; ?>" +"&uID="+"<?php echo $memID; ?>" +"&acctDB="+"profile" ,
        dataType: "dataString",
        success: function(data){
            $('#results').html('Success').delay(1000).fadeOut();
        }
    });
});
});
</script>
```

I am trying to get the message 'Success' to populate this span element;

```
<span id="results"></span>
```

But just can't seem to get it to work.

The PHP is as follows (the table is updated just fine);

```
if($_POST['acctDB'] == 'profile') {
$uemail = $DB->real_escape_string($_POST['uemail']);
$uage = $DB->real_escape_string($_POST['uage']);
$city = $DB->real_escape_string($_POST['city']);
$urname = $DB->real_escape_string($_POST['urname']);
$uname = $DB->real_escape_string($_POST['uname']);
$uID = $DB->real_escape_string($_POST['uID']);
mysqli_query($DB, 'UPDATE profile SET memEmail="'.$uemail.'", memAge="'.$uage.'", memCity="'.$city.'", memRealName="'.$urname.'" WHERE memID="'.$uID.'" AND memUname="'.$uname.'" ') or die(mysqli_error($DB));
}
```

Anyone be of assistance please?

Comment: Can you put success: function(data){ console.log("yes");} and verify that success callback is really called?

Comment: Also could you specify what doesn't work? Won't it set the content to "Success"? Won't it fade?

Comment: Hi, the content does not appear at all.  I installed Firebug just now but nothing shows in Console Log. Not used it before.

Comment: And also try by writing exit(); at the end of your php script..

Comment: You need to figure out *why* it doesn't work. Look in the Net tab of your developer tools — do you see the request and response? Are they formatted the way you expect? Are there error codes? — and in the Console tab — are there JavaScript errors? — then you have a `success` function, but you haven't bothered to write an `error` function. jQuery passes `error` three arguments, **look at them** and they will give you clues as to what the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the script as follows

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url:"acctUpdate.php",
        data: "uemail=" + uemail +"&uage="+ uage +"&city="+ city +"&urname="+urname +"&uname="+"<?php echo $memName; ?>" +"&uID="+"<?php echo $memID; ?>" +"&acctDB="+"profile" ,
       // dataType: "dataString",
        dataType : "text",
        success: function(data){
            $('#results').html(data).delay(1000).fadeOut();
            return false;
        }
    });
 return false;
```

In php file change this

```
$qry = mysqli_query($DB, 'UPDATE profile SET memEmail="'.$uemail.'", memAge="'.$uage.'", memCity="'.$city.'", memRealName="'.$urname.'" WHERE memID="'.$uID.'" AND memUname="'.$uname.'" ') or die(mysqli_error($DB));

if($qry)
    echo "Success";
}
```

Comment: That did it !! Thank you very much indeed!

Answer (score 3):

`dataType: "dataString"`

Please comment this part and it will work.

```
if($_POST['acctDB'] == 'profile') {

$uemail = $DB->real_escape_string($_POST['uemail']);

$uage = $DB->real_escape_string($_POST['uage']);

$city = $DB->real_escape_string($_POST['city']);

$urname = $DB->real_escape_string($_POST['urname']);

$uname = $DB->real_escape_string($_POST['uname']);

$uID = $DB->real_escape_string($_POST['uID']);

mysqli_query($DB, 'UPDATE profile SET memEmail="'.$uemail.'", memAge="'.$uage.'", memCity="'.$city.'", memRealName="'.$urname.'" WHERE memID="'.$uID.'" AND memUname="'.$uname.'" ') or die(mysqli_error($DB));

echo 'yes';

}

// add echo 'yes'; at php submit page.
```

Comment: Sorry no, the Success span still did not display.

Comment: Please add echo 'Yes'; to the response page and you can check by adding    success: function(data){
   //alert(data);
   console.log('yes');
            $('#results').html('Success').delay(1000).fadeOut();
        }

Comment: console.log('yes'); it will return the yes message.

Comment: Sorry Amit, that did not seem to do anything.

Comment: there is error in your response file. <?php

if($_POST['acctDB'] == 'profile') {

echo 'yes';

} 

?>
//this is working fine

Comment: you can check by deleting all line except echo 'yes'; and you can directly check by writing console.log('yes');

Comment: $uemail = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['uemail']); use this and everything will work.

Answer (score 0):

When you make an ajax call and you pass the values to a php file, you will also need to return the response.

So at the end of your query if everything is completed successful you will do something like this:

```
return Response::json(array(
            'success' => true,
            'message'  => trans('admin.update_success'),
        ), 200);
```

And your ajax cal looks something like this:

```
$("#submitValue").click(function(e){
        var uemail=$("#uemail").val();
        var uage=$("#uage").val();
        var city=$("#city").val();
        var urname=$("#urname").val();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'acctUpdate.php',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: "uemail=" + uemail +"&uage="+ uage +"&city="+ city +"&urname="+urname +"&uname="+"<?php echo $memName; ?>" +"&uID="+"<?php echo $memID; ?>" +"&acctDB="+"profile" ,
        dataType: "dataString",
    })
    .done(function(response) {
        alert(response.message)

    })
    .fail(function(response) {
        if (response.status == 400) {
            var output = '<ul>';
            var errors = $.parseJSON(response.responseText).errors;
            $.each(errors, function(id, message) {
                output += '<li>' + message[0] + '</li>'
            });
            output += '</ul>'
            alert(output)
        } else {
        alert('UnknownError');
        }
    })
    e.preventDefault();
})
```

So to recap:

You make the ajax call
The php file will process the data
You pass the response back to the 'done function)
And hier you can make anything you want with your response.

I have just as example inserted an alert message

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry, this does not even update the database and still does not return any message.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but the code I have provider for you is for a Laravel framework and I suppose you are not using it. So you don't have the 'Respone::' class.

In the php file:

```
      //if the query has success 
        $return = array();

        $return['responseCode'] = 1;
        $return['responseHTML'] = 'Success'



        echo json_encode( $return );
```

And the ajax call:

```
$("#submitValue").click(function(e){
        var uemail=$("#uemail").val();
        var uage=$("#uage").val();
        var city=$("#city").val();
        var urname=$("#urname").val();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'acctUpdate.php',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: "uemail=" + uemail +"&uage="+ uage +"&city="+ city +"&urname="+urname +"&uname="+"<?php echo $memName; ?>" +"&uID="+"<?php echo $memID; ?>" +"&acctDB="+"profile" ,

    })
    .done(function(response) {
        if( response.responseCode == 0 ) {
            //alert(respomse.responseHTML)
          $('#results').html(response.responseHTML);
        } else if( response.responseCode == 1 ) {
            //alert(res.responseHTML)
          $('#results').html(response.responseHTML);
        }

    })

    e.preventDefault();
})
```

So I don't use the response anymore but I will just return an array with the response.

Comment: Sorry, failed to insert also. Thank you for your time though.